# MicroPython uasyncio behaves differently on micro controller and regular Python: task just keeps running

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, microcontroller, micropython

This is my example:

```py
try:
    import uasyncio as asyncio
except ImportError:
    import asyncio

async def count():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(count())
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.run(main())
```

In regular Python, I get:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

However, MicroPython produces the following output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
5
1
6
2
7
3
8
4
9
```

So the first task doesn't stop but keeps running during the runtime of the second task.

Comment: Yes, same thing with the UNIX port on macOS 10.12.6. `MicroPython v1.16-39-g4ada56d4c-dirty on 2021-06-28; darwin version`.  So it's not just the RP2 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a defect and I've logged issue [#7471](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/7471) to track it (there's also a workaround there). Thanks for reporting the problem with a clear, reproducible example!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is currently expected behavior:

> By default uasyncio retains state, as [discussed here](https://github.com/peterhinch/micropython-async/blob/master/v3/docs/TUTORIAL.md#72-uasyncio-retains-state). Arguably in the interests of CPython compatibility it shouldn't, but on occasion this behaviour can be useful. Currently the user has the choice of whether to allow retained state.

Source: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/7471

Therefore, a work-around would be to call `asyncio.new_event_loop` in between subsequent calls of `asyncio.run`:

```py
try:
    import uasyncio as asyncio
except ImportError:
    import asyncio

async def count():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(count())
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

asyncio.run(main())
asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.run(main())
```